# How to keep the current location dot on the centre of the map when moving?

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2, currentlocation

So, I am creating an App, where I am adding multiple Geo-Fencing. But, as my current location is moving but the map is not moving, so the current location is going outside the map view. To summarize, the current location dot is not in the center of the map while it's moving. So, what changes I need to make. Kindly, reply.

Here is my Hotspot.class (Java)

```java
package com.example.testaid;


public class Hotspot extends AppCompatActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback, GeoQueryEventListener {

    private GoogleMap mMap;
    private FusedLocationProviderClient mFusedLocationProviderClient;
    private PlacesClient placesClient;
    private List<AutocompletePrediction> predictionList;
    private DatabaseReference myLocationRef;
    private GeoFire geoFire;
    private List<LatLng> dangerousArea;

    private Location mLastKnownLocation;
    private LocationCallback locationCallback;

    private MaterialSearchBar materialSearchBar;
    private View mapView;

    private final float DEFAULT_ZOOM = 18;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_hotspot);
        Window w = getWindow();

        w.setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

        //Maps
        materialSearchBar = findViewById(R.id.searchBar);

        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
        settingGeoFire();

        initArea();

        mapView = mapFragment.getView();
        mFusedLocationProviderClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(Hotspot.this);
        Places.initialize(Hotspot.this, "Your API key");
        placesClient = Places.createClient(this);
        AutocompleteSessionToken token = AutocompleteSessionToken.newInstance();

        //Bottom Navigation Bar
        BottomNavigationView bottomNavigationView = findViewById(R.id.bottom_nav);

        bottomNavigationView.setSelectedItemId(R.id.hotspot);

        bottomNavigationView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem menuItem) {
                switch (menuItem.getItemId()) {
                    case R.id.home:
                        startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext()
                                , MainActivity.class));
                        overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
                        return true;
                    case R.id.cars:
                        startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext()
                                , Shipping.class));
                        overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
                        return true;
                    case R.id.news:
                        startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext()
                                , News.class));
                        overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
                        return true;

                }
                return false;
            }
        });
    }

    private void initArea() {
        dangerousArea = new ArrayList<>();
        dangerousArea.add(new LatLng(x,y));
    }

    private void settingGeoFire() {
        myLocationRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("My Location");
        geoFire = new GeoFire(myLocationRef);
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;
        mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        mMap.isBuildingsEnabled();
        mMap.getUiSettings().setCompassEnabled(true);
        mMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(true);

        if (mapView !=null && mapView.findViewById(Integer.parseInt("1")) != null) {
            View locationButton = ((View) mapView.findViewById(Integer.parseInt("1")).getParent()).findViewById(Integer.parseInt("2"));
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) locationButton.getLayoutParams();
            layoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP,0);
            layoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
            layoutParams.setMargins(0,0,40,180);
        }
        if (mapView !=null && mapView.findViewById(Integer.parseInt("1")) != null) {
            View locationCompass = ((View) mapView.findViewById(Integer.parseInt("1")).getParent()).findViewById(Integer.parseInt("5"));
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) locationCompass.getLayoutParams();
            layoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
            layoutParams.setMargins(0,200,30,0);
        }

        //check if location is enabled
        LocationRequest locationRequest = LocationRequest.create();
        locationRequest.setInterval(10000);
        locationRequest.setFastestInterval(3000);
        locationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);

        LocationSettingsRequest.Builder builder = new LocationSettingsRequest.Builder().addLocationRequest(locationRequest);

        SettingsClient settingsClient = LocationServices.getSettingsClient(Hotspot.this);
        Task<LocationSettingsResponse> task = settingsClient.checkLocationSettings(builder.build());

        task.addOnSuccessListener(Hotspot.this, new OnSuccessListener<LocationSettingsResponse>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(LocationSettingsResponse locationSettingsResponse) {
                getDeviceLocation();

            }
        });
        task.addOnFailureListener(Hotspot.this, new OnFailureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                if (e instanceof ResolvableApiException){
                    ResolvableApiException resolvable = (ResolvableApiException) e;
                    try {
                        resolvable.startResolutionForResult(Hotspot.this, 51);
                    } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e1) {
                        e1.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        });

        for (LatLng latLng :dangerousArea )
        {
            mMap.addCircle(new CircleOptions().center(latLng)
            .radius(200)
                    .strokeColor(Color.RED)
                    .fillColor(0x220000FF)
                    .strokeWidth(5.0f)
            );

            GeoQuery geoQuery = geoFire.queryAtLocation(new GeoLocation(latLng.latitude,latLng.longitude),0.2f); // 500m
            geoQuery.addGeoQueryEventListener(Hotspot.this);
        }

    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if(requestCode == 51) {
            if (requestCode == RESULT_OK) {
                getDeviceLocation();
            }
        }
    }
    private void getDeviceLocation (){
        mFusedLocationProviderClient.getLastLocation()
                .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Location>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Location> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()){
                            mLastKnownLocation = task.getResult();
                            if(mLastKnownLocation != null){
                                mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(mLastKnownLocation.getLatitude(), mLastKnownLocation.getLongitude()), DEFAULT_ZOOM));
                            } else {
                                final LocationRequest locationRequest = LocationRequest.create();
                                locationRequest.setInterval(10000);
                                locationRequest.setFastestInterval(3000);
                                locationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
                                locationCallback = new LocationCallback() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onLocationResult(LocationResult locationResult) {
                                        super.onLocationResult(locationResult);
                                        if (locationResult == null){
                                            return;
                                        }
                                        mLastKnownLocation = locationResult.getLastLocation();
                                        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(mLastKnownLocation.getLatitude(),mLastKnownLocation.getLongitude()), DEFAULT_ZOOM));
                                         mFusedLocationProviderClient.removeLocationUpdates(locationCallback);
                                    }
                                };
                                mFusedLocationProviderClient.requestLocationUpdates(locationRequest, locationCallback, null);
                            }
                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(Hotspot.this, "Unable to Get Last Location", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }
                });

    }

    @Override
    public void onKeyEntered(String key, GeoLocation location) {
        sendNotification("TestAid",String.format("%s entered the dangerous area ", key));
    }

    @Override
    public void onKeyExited(String key) {
        sendNotification("TestAid",String.format("%s leave the dangerous area ", key));
    }

    @Override
    public void onKeyMoved(String key, GeoLocation location) {
        sendNotification("TestAid",String.format("%s move within the dangerous area ", key));
    }

    @Override
    public void onGeoQueryReady() {

    }

    @Override
    public void onGeoQueryError(DatabaseError error) {
        Toast.makeText(this, ""+error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    private void sendNotification(String title, String content) {
        Toast.makeText(this, ""+content, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        String NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID = "TESTAID_MULTIPLE_LOCATION";
        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
        {
            NotificationChannel notificationChannel = new NotificationChannel(NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID, "My Notification",
                    NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT);

            notificationChannel.setDescription("Channel Description");
            notificationChannel.enableLights(true);
            notificationChannel.setLightColor(Color.RED);
            notificationChannel.setVibrationPattern(new long[] {0,1000, 500, 1000});
            notificationChannel.enableVibration(true);
            notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(notificationChannel);

        }

        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this,NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID);
        builder.setContentTitle(title)
                .setContentText(content)
                .setAutoCancel(false)
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
        .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.mipmap.ic_launcher));

        Notification notification = builder.build();
        notificationManager.notify(new Random().nextInt(),notification);
    }
}
```

There are two XML Layout, one is Content Layout, other is Activity Layout

Activity Layout

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#00FFFF00"
    tools:context=".Hotspot"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bottom_nav"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="55dp"
        android:elevation="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/rounded"
        app:itemIconTint="@color/nav_color"
        app:itemTextColor="@color/nav_color"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:menu="@menu/menu_bottom" />

    <include layout="@layout/content_hotspot_"/>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Content Layout

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context=".Hotspot"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_hotspot"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

    <com.mancj.materialsearchbar.MaterialSearchBar
        style="@style/MaterialSearchBarLight"

        app:mt_speechMode="false"
        app:mt_hint="Search"
        app:mt_maxSuggestionsCount="10"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/searchBar"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        app:mt_placeholder="Search"
        android:outlineProvider="bounds"
        android:elevation="5dp"/>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: val base = LatLng(36.28849428505936, 59.61559161543847)
                    mMap.addMarker(MarkerOptions().position(base).title("Holy Shrine"))
                    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(base, 14f))

Comment: Please remove all references to Android Sudio. It has nothing to do with your problem.